# Exporting georeferenced collada from ArcGIS Pro to Sketchup

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, 3d-analyst, sketchup, collada

Using the Multipatch to Collada conversion tool on ArcGIS Pro I have been able to export 3D models and open them in Sketchup maintaining their 3D features, however they lose their spatial reference and appear as individual entities floating around in space.

What can I do to keep the spatial reference of the exported 3D files in Sketchup?

Comment: Hi Posad. Did you every work this out?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately not. We gave it a few attempts and that's it. Would be happy to hear if you come about a solution!